# Object initialization in Python

Tags: python, class, object, initialization

I've created a simple class with object that has init value **x0**. When I change another value **x**, my **x0** is also changing.

I thought that **x0** should remain unchanged. Could you please explain why is this happening?

**file main.py:**

```
import numpy as np
from simpleclass import test


def main():

    params = dict()
    params['position'] = np.array([1.0, 2.0])

    object = test(params)

    print(object.x0)
    print(object.x)

    object.run(2)

    print(object.x0)
    print(object.x)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

file **simpleclass.py:**

```
class test():

    def __init__(self, params):
        self.x0 = params['position']
        self.x = self.x0

    def run(self, num):
        self.x += self.x*num
```

**result:**

```
[ 1.  2.]
[ 1.  2.]
[ 3.  6.]
[ 3.  6.]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

problem is with

```
class test():
    def __init__(self, params):
        self.x0 = params['position']
        self.x = self.x0

    def run(self, num):
        self.x += self.x*num
```

`self.x = self.x0` here self.x and self.x0 are pointing same object. you can make copy of self.x0.

```
import copy

class test():
    def __init__(self, params):
        self.x0 = params['position']
        self.x = copy.deepcopy(self.x0)

    def run(self, num):
        self.x += self.x*num
```

Answer (score 1):

surya singh is right, just print the memory address, you will get the same numbers

```
class test():
    def __init__(self, params):
        self.x0 = params['position']
        self.x = self.x0
        print id(self.x)
        print id(self.x0)
```

Comment: Thanks!
I will keep this in mind

Answer (score 1):

### You are only passing a reference

By `self.x = self.x0`, you are only passing a reference. With `self.x += self.x*num`, the reference is unchanged too. So after those two operations, *x* and *x0* still points to the same array.

It would be different if you used an immutable object, such as *tuple*

```
params['position'] = (1, 2)
```

With *tuple*, `+=` does something different than what you want, but you see, *x* and *x0* points to different object.

```
(1, 2)
(1, 2)
(1, 2)
(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)
```

### Use a copy

You want to create a copy of your array, numpy has a [built-in method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.copy.html#numpy.ndarray.copy) for that

```
self.x = self.x0.copy()
```

Result:

```
[ 1.  2.]
[ 1.  2.]
[ 1.  2.]
[ 3.  6.]
```